# Date conversion incorrect for year in R

Tags: r

I am struggling converting a column into the correct date format.

My original data is displaying in this format in Excel: "08-Sep-23" but when I double click on the cell the format that it shows is 08-09-2023.

I imported the .xlsx file into R using the "import(here(" functions. It then morphed the dates into the 44XXXX format.

I converted to numeric and then to as.Date using this:

```r
mutate(visit_date = as.numeric(visit_date)) %>% 
   mutate(visit_date = as.Date(visit_date))
```

But now I am getting dates that look like this:

2093-09-08

Ideally I would like the dates to import in the format 2023-09-08

What is the most elegant solution for this? I feel like I'm writing so much code to do something very basic.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use origin:

```
mutate(visit_date = as.numeric(visit_date)) %>%
    mutate(visit_date = as.Date(visit_date, origin = "1899-12-30"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel date numbers can be converted to R Date format with the excel_numeric_to_date() function in the janitor package.

```
> janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(40000)
[1] "2009-07-06"
```

Dates are not stored in a particular format in R, you only need to apply the format you want when you print them.